# How to distinguish the two entities with the same Entity Set name and same Entity name in two ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

There are two edmx files in my project, each of them connected to different database, but the databases have the same schema, I want to query out records and add to the other database, but when I compile my project, I received the error message:

Ambiguity between 'ConsoleApplication17.Person._id' and 'ConsoleApplication17.Person._id'

A partial method may not have multiple defining declarations

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two databases with the same schema you don't need two EDMX files. You jus need one and two connection strings. The exception most probably means ambiguity in mapping (everything is defined twice) or entity classes generated twice (for every EDMX).

Comment: Hi Ladislav, could you give a sample how to give one edmx file two connection string?

Comment: You will not give one EDMX two connection strings. You will need to pass the connection string to constructor of your context. `ObjectContext` has multiple overloaded  constructors. If autogenerated class derived from `ObjectContext` doesn't provide constructor accepting connection string you can add your own (autogenerated classes are partial so you can add your own partial part with a new constructor).